# SQLite to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I wrote function which puts some values in a list view but the app is crashing with that error -

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

here is the function-

```
    public void SetInList() {
    {
        database = UserInfo_Activity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Runs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                TABLE_NAME + "", null);
        try {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String Date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                        int steps = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Steps"));
                        String Time = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Time"));
                        double Distance = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Distance"));


                        Runs.add(Date + "  " + Distance + "  " + Time);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), se.toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserInfo_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Runs);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The error is related to this line- list.setAdapter(adapter);
and I cant understand why

Here the entire class-

```
package com.exemple.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserInfo_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    private String TABLE_NAME = "RunningLog";
    private ArrayList<String> Runs;
    private ListView list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_info_);

    ArrayList<String> Runs = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    database = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Runs", 0, null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_NAME +
            " (Date VARCHAR," +
            " Time VARCHAR, steps INT, distance DOUBLE);");

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    SetInList();
}

public void SetInList() {
    {
        database = UserInfo_Activity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("Runs", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                TABLE_NAME + "", null);
        try {
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String Date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                        int steps = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Steps"));
                        String Time = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Time"));
                        double Distance = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Distance"));


                        Runs.add(Date + "  " + Distance + "  " + Time);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), se.toString());
        }

        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserInfo_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Runs);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again you have declared two Runs one global and one local to the method. Use only the global one.

So change your code like this

Old

```
ArrayList<String> Runs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

New

```
Runs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Yes I did (on the OnCreate())
        ArrayList<String> Runs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

Comment: Let me know if it helped?

Comment: Ok null pointer has been solved. Now. It might be another new issue.  Post that as well.

Comment: @NadavKadar Yes same kind of issue. I updated the answer. let me know if it helped.